# Space is Worspace name is causing java.net.URISyntaxException

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, cucumber

I am working on a Selenium Project where the Workspace name I was using had a space because of which I was getting following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: C:/Users/xyz/eclipse-workspace ValveAware/TestProject/src/test/resources/features/Administration/Export.feature is not valid. Try URI[:LINE]*
    at io.cucumber.core.model.FeatureWithLines.parse(FeatureWithLines.java:56)
    at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.parse(RuntimeOptions.java:189)
    at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.<init>(RuntimeOptions.java:107)
    at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.<init>(RuntimeOptions.java:100)
    at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.<init>(RuntimeOptions.java:96)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime$Builder.withArgs(Runtime.java:131)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime$Builder.withArgs(Runtime.java:127)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:22)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 36: C:/Users/xyz/eclipse-workspace ValveAware/TestProject/src/test/resources/features/Administration/Export.feature
    at java.base/java.net.URI.create(URI.java:883)
    at io.cucumber.core.model.FeaturePath.parseProbableURI(FeaturePath.java:44)
    at io.cucumber.core.model.FeaturePath.parse(FeaturePath.java:37)
    at io.cucumber.core.model.FeatureWithLines.parseFeaturePath(FeatureWithLines.java:77)
    at io.cucumber.core.model.FeatureWithLines.parse(FeatureWithLines.java:53)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 36: C:/Users/xyz/eclipse-workspace ValveAware/TestProject/src/test/resources/features/Administration/Export.feature
    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2915)
    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3086)
    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3168)
    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3116)
    at java.base/java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:600)
    at java.base/java.net.URI.create(URI.java:881)
    ... 12 more
```

I changed the name of the workspace and removed the space. I checked the path of the file Export.feature and the space is not there. But when I execute this file, I am still getting the same error.

Runner File:

```
package valveAware.port.localhost.tests;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;

@CucumberOptions(
        features = { "src/test/resources/features/Administration/Export.feature" }, 
        monochrome = true,
        plugin = { "pretty","html:target/Destination" }, 
        glue = { "valveAware.port.localhost.tests" }
        )



public class ValveAwareRunnerTest extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests{

}
```

Comment: Just use this --"src/test/resources/features/Administration/Export.feature"

Comment: Are you talking about Runner File? Editted the above question with Runner file.

Comment: Yes seems about right

Comment: yeah. Thats why I am also confused

Comment: One thing to notice, it has nothing to do with the Runner File. Irrespective of the changes I do in the Runner file, I am getting the same error.

Comment: Then your changes are not compiling

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188409/discussion-between-neha-and-grasshopper).

Comment: Are you using eclipse or idea to run your feature?

Comment: This issue has been resolved. BTW I am using Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new workspace and imported the projects, then it worked